# system freeze when doing pandas.merge()

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I'm running Win7 64Bit on 4GB RAM. I read a large data file (3Mio rows to read) into a Pandas dataframe, do several isin()-Operations and obtain 2 other dataframes df1 and df2, each having 300000 lines. Until here everything is fine, total memory consumption is around 40%. However, when I try to merge df1 and df2, RAM consumption goes directly up to almost 100% and a a system freeze results. Looks like a memory leak. Anybody observing something silimar? What happens under the roof of pandas.merge() that leads to that? Any possibility to get the code running? The merge command:

```
merged=pandas.merge(df1, df2, on=['call/put','expiration'], how='inner', left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Comment: When there are N records in df1 that match M records in df2 it generates N x M records which shows up as system slowness. I suspect your problem is that the 'on' argument is missing some columns - strike/symbol etc

Comment: Only a part of the columns is within on[]. 4 columns are not included. Both frames have same dimension, about 300000 rows x 8 columns including index.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to provide some example data on this. I suspect your join is going many to one or something. I tried to set up an example with 6 columns and I was able to do the join with 50,000,000 records on my MBP in about 2 minutes.

I'm running in Ipython notebook so I used the cell magic %%time to calculate run time of the cells.

Here's my example:

```
%%time
np.random.seed(1)
n=50000000 #50,000,000
df1 = pd.DataFrame(randn(n), index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=n))
df1.columns = ['thing1']
df1['thing2'] = randn(n)
df1['thing3'] = randn(n)
df1['thing4'] = randn(n)
df1['call/put'] = np.random.choice(['put','call'], n)
df1['expiration'] = pd.date_range('1/1/2001', periods=n)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(randn(n), index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=n))
df2.columns = ['thing1']
df2['thing2'] = randn(n)
df2['thing3'] = randn(n)
df2['thing4'] = randn(n)
df2['call/put'] = np.random.choice(['put','call'], n)
df2['expiration'] = pd.date_range('1/1/2001', periods=n)
```

That takes about 40 seconds on my box.

```
print df1.head()
print df2.head()

             thing1    thing2    thing3    thing4 call/put expiration
2000-01-01  1.624345 -1.139160 -1.226383 -0.157804     call 2001-01-01
2000-01-02 -0.611756 -0.082128 -0.982924  0.254592     call 2001-01-02
2000-01-03 -0.528172 -1.601699  0.457530 -0.671379      put 2001-01-03
2000-01-04 -1.072969  0.496285 -1.747807  0.181793      put 2001-01-04
2000-01-05  0.865408 -1.481422 -0.435733  1.582169     call 2001-01-05
              thing1    thing2    thing3    thing4 call/put expiration
2000-01-01 -0.020954  0.054025  2.502060  1.011011     call 2001-01-01
2000-01-02  0.635003 -1.757002 -0.311092  1.469307     call 2001-01-02
2000-01-03  1.547721  0.267789 -2.703976  0.671766      put 2001-01-03
2000-01-04 -1.288127 -0.745521  0.614661  0.897899     call 2001-01-04
2000-01-05  0.094685 -0.451766 -0.012700 -0.641612      put 2001-01-05
```

then I do the merge:

```
%%time
merged=pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['call/put','expiration'], how='inner', left_index=True, right_index=True)

CPU times: user 20.3 s, sys: 19 s, total: 39.3 s
Wall time: 1min 58s
```

So what might be different between your real data and the dummy example here?

Comment: When I run your example with 50 Mio rows creation of df1 took 12 minutes, creation of df2 36minutes, then there was a message: It seems the kernel died unexpectedly. Use 'Restart kernel' to continue using this console.
Trying to merge then resultied in a memory error. I run on WIn7 with 4 GB. And you?

Comment: I'm on a MBP with 8GB ram but have a win VM running using >2GB. You really should consider upgrading your RAM. 16GB of RAM is under $200 (presuming you are in the USA)

Comment: What is MBP? I still wonder why pandas.merge leads to memory error, since process should be slow, but not result in an error. Do you run Python on Linux or Windows?

Comment: MBP = MacBook Pro. So I run on a Mac. Sometimes in Linux.

Comment: are you running a 64 bit version of Python or a 32 bit?

Comment: I'm running 64bit Python.

Comment: do you get the same result if you run the code from ipython at the command prompt instead of the notebook?